# When I export with the command flutter build app it generates complex JavaScript code, but I want only HTML, CSS and JavaScript code, is it Possible?

Tags: django, flutter, web

When I exported my project with the command `flutter build web`. It generated complex **JavaScript** code, but I want only **HTML**,**CSS** and **Javascript** code. Is it Possible? I have intended to make the front end with flutter and the back with django after exporting, but it is generating complex JS code I can't get **HTML** tags and **CSS** styling. Please help me if you have any idea how to.

When I export with the command flutter build app it generates complex JavaScript code, but I want only HTML, CSS and JavaScript code, is it Possible?

Comment: Why do you need HTML tags and CSS styling?

Comment: because i am familiar building django web apps with html tags and loading static files with css and javascript

Comment: I don't think that it is possible (or useful). If you want html, css and js react native could be a better option. To utilize flutters cross-platform capabilities, you have to use dart and the flutter framework.